# Disable Specific Widgets on Selected Pages of a WordPress Website?

Tags: plugins, widgets, customization

I would like to give a CMS look to some of my pages. I want to customize them by removing the default widgets and adding other widgets as my wish (I will use plugins like [**My Custom Widget**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mycustomwidget/)  to add custom codes if I need) .

Is there any possibility to customize the specific pages like this?

Comment: [Widget Display Options](https://dojodigital.com/blog/2013/05/03/dojo-digital-launches-widget-display-options/) Here's another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin, [WidgetLogic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/).

From the description:

> This plugin gives every widget an extra control field called "Widget logic" that lets you control the pages that the widget will appear on.

I've used it successfully.

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer (you got my +1)

Answer (score 1):

The other option that I know of is called [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/).

It is slightly more complex than Widget Logic, but it doesn't require the use of any conditional tags, which can be intimidating for non-coders.

You can show/hide widgets on selected pages, posts, archives and more.